# What kind of eye strain causes an visual aurora effect?

Tags: neuroscience, eyes

When I have done too much reading on the PC sometimes I feel a tickling sensation inside my eyeball. At first I didn't even notice the tickle, however my eye would start to see blurred in one area, and a growing halo of yellow blue orange stars grows outwards from one place in my visual field. the shape is not very round, it growns like a mycelium shape, where the border is very bright with stars and lights.

So the effect resembles a mushroom growth ebbing slowly outwards from a point over the space of 30-45 minutes, where my vision in one eye becomes overcome with a blurring effect and a flashing colored araura, and an annoying tickling/electrical effect inside the eyeball. it can be more or less pronounced, and sometimes I can barely read anything up to 1 hour afterwards, and after 2 hours it has returned to normal.

I have 9.5/10 visual acuity, and this started occuring every few months since I was 33.

I can't find what I am experiencing, all the eye disorders and symptoms seem to describe different issues than what i have.

What can it be?

Comment: That's called a scintillating scotoma, and it should be present in both eyes (cover one eye when it's happening and see if it isn't the same in the other.) Look it up. It's a kind of a migraine. It's not serious (honest), but you should let your doctor know you're having them. I have them too. I think they're fascinating.

Comment: Thanks that's a very good answer, if you write it as the answer i'll mark it as true.

Comment: We're not supposed to answer medical questions. :(

Comment: I'll have to check if it is unilateral and if my irises are the same size afterwards. I found a page which sais that some versions can be caused in the retina: https://www.reviewofoptometry.com/article/visual-aura--and-scotomas-what-do-they-indicate there's masses of pictures of scintillating scotoma on the image search too. thanks again.

Comment: most ocular migraines can't be medicated and they are more "trippy" than than noxious. It's also a neuroscience and optical quesiton. anyways, the answer helped a lot with knowledge.

Comment: They are *trippy* to me as well. They are treatable if serious enough. I can't read without great difficulty when I get one. Luckily, it never happened to me at work!